# How should I respond to bidirectional loss of trust with my management?

Tags: manager

It's clear that my management doesn't trust me to do my job or to accept criticism. I don't trust them to have my back, or to judge my work, or to use me effectively, or to accept criticism.

I don't feel that I can perform my duties effectively if I'm not trusted, or if I don't trust my management. But I also believe the company as an entity would prefer to keep me around, all other things being equal. As I would prefer to stay.

I do not know how to resolve this situation.

**How can I regain the trust of management? How can I learn to trust management?**

Comment: What's your goal? To make management trust you? To be able to trust management? To get a new boss? To find a new job?

Comment: Are there any possible reasons that the regional manager might have for encouraging you to find another position? Often this sort of behavior is a way to encourage employees to leave when there’s no good reason to fire them. Sometimes new management wants to replace existing employees with their own people. Is anyone else on your team having difficulty with the new manager?

Comment: @AffableAmbler my preferred outcome is to stay with the company. Moving to another office isn't an option, though.

Comment: @ColleenV my understanding is that this regional manager has been problematic for a while. There's almost no way he would have anyone to replace me with, given the nature of this work.

Answer (score 9):

Your direct manager is more important than anyone else.They're the buffer between you and the rest of the World. If you're finding them toxic you have few options.

Prove them wrong by ignoring the negative and doing solid work until he/she stops.

Complain to higher up, which is a potential disaster for you with unknown benefits.

Job search, I'd actually job search until I either had leverage to get moved or otherwise improve my situation if it was toxic enough, but I've had plenty of bad managers and just soldiered on, all I care about is being paid.

Answer (score 6):

> The management above these two, and parallel to them, and almost literally everyone else in the company, seems to think I do good work. Reviews of my work done by other parties besides these two have generally gone very well. I'm not aware anyone considers me difficult to work with. So I don't think it's me.

Request a transfer that takes you out from under the people with whom you have difficulties and puts you under the people whom respect your work. If others feel the same way and do the same something's gotta give.

Make clear your reasons in person when upper management asks, but don't so much 'spell it out' on your written request. If it is them and not you then your *voice* will serve as a reminder of prior complaints, if they are only messing with you and no one else you have some risk associated with complaining.

If you are getting modest pay you are certain to be paid more elsewhere, as you'd possibly not take the position otherwise. Alternatively somewhere else that's closer to your home or a 'center of numerous better opportunities', and pays similar or less, cuts the neysayers out of your daily grind and leaves them shorthanded.